# What is meant with "The result is not considered to be constant"

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

In the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), I found this sentence:

> The result of a ?? operator is not considered to be a constant even if both its arguments are constants.

What does this signify? Do they mean that the compiler optimiser does not know that this value is constant? I don't see another way this could be relevant.

*Edit:* And why is this not considered constant? Is there a logical reason for it?

*Edit:* This piece of code gives a compiler error for x, but not for y, why can `?:` result in a constant value, but `??` cannot?

```
const string NULL = null;
const string val = "value";
const string x = NULL ?? val;
const string y = NULL == null ? val : NULL;
```

Comment: Maybe that simply accent on that it can't be used where compiler (language specification?) expects constant expressions, e.g. as field initiliazer.

Comment: It means exactly what it says - you cannot use the result where a constant is expected - for example assigning to another constant of the same type.

Comment: Let's wait for @ericlippert :) Until then we can only guess

Comment: as to the logical reason for it you would have to as MS for the definitive answer, but using a constant with ?? is logically pointless why use a coalesce on a fixed known value `const string = "a string" ?? "null"` is never going to be null and `const string = null ?? "null"` will always be "null" so the right hand should be used with out ??

Comment: @MikeT Except that constants could depend on precompiler directives. I'm not saying it's a good idea, but it is certainly common enough to matter. In any case, your argument would apply the same to the `?:` or `+` operators, and yet those are allowed :)

Comment: @Luaan that is certainly true for inline if and many of the other operators, however it isn't true for coalesce because the result isn't a constant, and the above is the most logical reason i can think of for why it wouldn't be

Comment: @MikeT Yes, but that begs the question. You just said that it's value isn't constant, because it isn't constant. Which obviously means it can't be constant. *Why* isn't the result constant, when the result of `?:` and `+` *is* constant, despite the fact that the same reasoning applies (e.g. why `stringConstant == null ? "null" : stringConstant` is fine but `stringConstant ?? "null"` isn't?)

Comment: @Luaan I said "it isn't constant, so it can't be constant" which is a simple logical statement like "Red can't be blue", and then gave a reason why that might be, your eg is a work around to make it work, but has other uses ie IsLive ? "Live" : "Dev", under strict definition IsLive is not a Constant, but a CompileTimeVariable, (though from compiled code standpoint there is little difference) but CTV's should only be used for setting up the compiler and in most instances strings are meaningless to Computers, making them unlikely as CTV and no other constant type allows nulls

Comment: but we are getting off topic, so lets agree to disagree

Comment: @MikeT No, it's a simple logical statement like "A implies A". It has no information whatsoever. We know it isn't constant - that's what the documentation said. Explaining that it isn't constant because it isn't constant doesn't add anything.

Comment: I can think of use cases for const conditionals, eg, `const string Description = Internal ? "Internal build" : "Public build";`  I'm not super thrilled with using constants in this way -- I'd rather they be `readonly` than `const` -- but I can see why someone would do this. But I am at a loss to think of an example where I'd want to use `??` in a constant in production code. If there's no compelling use case then the feature doesn't get implemented. So what's your compelling realistic use case? If you can't find one then you know why there's no such feature.

Comment: @Luaan: And now you know why I push back on questions of the form "why does the language not do this?" A "why not?" question is hard to answer; it presupposes that the universe ought to be a way that it is not, and then demands an explanation. No one thinks that questions like "why weren't you born in France?" are reasonable, but somehow asking why language designers did *not* make a particular decision is thought to be fair game.

Comment: @EricLippert If only that was a problem exclusive to language design :) It seems that people intuitively expect things to be perfect, and the only reason they do not fit their expectations is that somebody broke that perfection for some reason. After all, that's a common theme in religion - things used to be perfect, but then <something>, and now we have to live with disasters/sin/starvation/etc. The idea that we're coming from some ideal world, and it's getting *worse* by human action. Things used to *feel* so much easier when I was writing DOS applications in Pascal :P

Comment: @EricLippert I didn't expect the language to include this feature, I just wanted to know why the feature was not implemented, when it obviously was known to the team, because they added a note to the documentation. "We didn't consider it" is also an answer to that question. I did not ask with the intention that it ought to be implemented.

Comment: @vrwim: We don't need to provide a reason to *not* implement a feature. Rather, the people who want the feature have to provide a reasoning that convinces the team that the feature is the best use of their limited available time and effort. Why should the design and implementation teams spend any time on features that no one wants and are not useful?

Comment: @EricLippert I know – you don't have to justify yourself, I was just curious whether it was a conscious decision to not have it be constant, or just something that was not implemented because of money, time, or other constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about usage of ?? operator in constant expressions. Is it *possible* in principle? Of course, because we have all required information at compile time. Is it implemented in C#? Nope. Why? Because C# compiler team *chose* not to implement this feature. Here is what [Eric Lippert says](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/10/08/the-future-of-c-part-one/) about selecting features which should be implemented:

> Features have to be so compelling that they are worth the enormous dollar costs of designing, implementing, testing, documenting and shipping the feature. They have to be worth the cost of complicating the language and making it more difficult to design other features in the future.

When we can use ?? operator in constant expression? When *expr-first* is a null literal. And constant type is either object or string (remember, C# team already decided not to add Nullables support for constants). And what this feature will *add* to the language?

```
const string s = null ?? "foo";
```

That does not add any convenience to the language. It's totally same as

```
const string s = "foo";
```

but more complicated.

Comment: @MikeT decimals can too. And you can use object as type of constant. Try `const object o = null`. But you can intialize it only with null literal

Comment: @MikeT seems like mistake. C# specification 7.19 says *A constant expression must be the null literal or a value with one of  the following types: sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, bool, **object**, string, or any enumeration type.*. And [compiler says same](http://rextester.com/VORX87254) :)

Comment: @MikeT as I wrote before *you can initialize object only with null literal*. 10 is not null literal

Comment: @MikeT `int` is not an `object`. Only the boxed int is an `object`. This can be a bit confusing, since `int`s are automatically boxed when necessary. It's just that the only valid constant for a reference type (excluding `string`) is `null`, but you can still make a `object` (or `Process` or whatever) constant. And `decimal` is not a built-in type (it's part of the extended numerics library), and yet can be a constant. And really, what should count as "built-in"? How is `int` and `DateTime` "built-in", while `Action` isn't? You're just making your own definitions to suit your argument.

Answer (score 4):

It means that you can't use the null-coalescing operator in a constant:

```
public const int MyInt = 42; // Fine
public const int MyOtherInt = new int?(42) ?? 8; // Compiler error
```

This is mainly in contrast to most other operators, where operands that are constant produce a result that is also constant:

```
public const int SomeResult = 12 + 42; // Fine
public const int OtherResult = SomeResult * 2; // Fine
```

This isn't really a matter of "optimisation" - in fact, the `??` operator is optimised away pretty heavily in most scenarios:

```
var someValue = new int?(42) ?? 8; // Produces ldc.i4.8
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to know *why* ?? operator with constant parameters do not produce constant value. E.g. you can use `?:` with constants to get constant. You can use `const string s = false ? null : "abc";` but you cannot `const string s = null ?? "abc";`

Comment: @Sinatr hmm from question it's clear that OP understands what is constants: *"Do they mean that the compiler optimiser does not know that this value is constant?"*  And his edit proves that

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy That was added to the question after my answer. But it's most likely off-topic anyway - it's not in the spec, so it's just an implementation detail of the current C# compiler. Unless someone from the compiler team can provide their reasoning, we're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you write code which could cause this error message, the answer will be apparent.

```
public void Test()
{
    const int x = ((int?)null ?? 3);
}
```

This generates the following error:

> Error 9   The expression being assigned to 'x' must be constant

So the compiler does not calculate the result of `??` at compile-time.

In contrast, many other operators such as `? :` are calculated at compile-time, so the following does not generate an error:

```
const int x = (true ? 3 : 2);
```

Comment: Actually, as shown in my example, the compiler does calculate the result of `??` at compile-time in most scenarios. I assume that constant evaluation simply happens before the others, and that's where it isn't allowed yet (for whatever reason).

Comment: doubtless Microsoft have deadlines, and I would guess adding an error message is quicker than fully-implementing the operator at compile-time.